# "Road liable to flooding" — is this roadsign grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, gerunds, signage

I passed the roadsign below while driving home late last night, and realised that despite how many times I had seen it, I was still surprised by the choice of words used and unsure if it was actually grammatically correct.

After all, the wording on roadsigns is crucial. As we all know, it needs to be clear and succinct.

So, to my mind the words

> Road liable to flooding

should be

> Road liable to *flood*

or it could be rewritten

> Road *prone* to flooding

Am I right, or is the original ok?

[image: photo of roadsign with text: Road liable to flooding]

Comment: How could it possibly be misunderstood? What do you think is ungrammatical about it?

Comment: I didn't say it could be misunderstood. Just that it was worded strangely. I think the word "liable" is being used wrongly. You wouldn't say "He took the test but he's liable to _failing_"- you'd say "_fail_"...surely?

Comment: 'Liable to' and 'prone to' are pretty much interchangeable. Elegance of text is not the primary focus here - immediate understanding is and this works just fine.

Comment: @TonyBalmforth Yeah, I guess it's clear enough. I'm just not sure it's grammatical.

Comment: In my opinion, "Beware of flooding" would be more immediately understandable because of its resemblance to "Beware of dog."

Comment: @skullpatrol: Except that, in this case, there's really only a danger during a time of heavy rain (and perhaps a winter thaw, if the region is mountainous).  In the case of the dog, we presume the dog is *always* ready to bite. But on a sunny day, we need not beware of anything on the road.  *Beware* carries the connotation that we need always be on alert.

Comment: Going by [Google's results](http://tinyurl.com/btkbylk), @Urbycoz is not the first person to question the correctness of this sign.

Comment: @J.R. Would "Beware of possible flooding" be acceptable?

Comment: @skullpatrol: I'd have no problem with "Beware of possible flooding"; I can envision a transportation subcommittee debating the merits of each.

Comment: I have always been curious about this kind of "signage dialect" - a particular style of incomplete sentences that seem to have their own grammatical rules. Similar to headlines.

Comment: @J.R.  May I add, that we have not taken into account the context of the sign of the red triangle with the exclamation mark within it, which is usually read as "caution!" Thus, the sign post should be read "Caution! Road liable to flooding".

Comment: What about [this](http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20080317131220/uncyclopedia/images/d/da/Dumb_sign.jpg) sign? :)

Comment: Personally, I just think that "susceptible" was too long for a road sign.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Road liable to flooding

The OED helpfully cites the above warning in its [definition of liable](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/liable):

> [with infinitive] likely to do or to be something:
>   *patients were liable to faint if they stood up too suddenly*
>
> (liable to) likely to experience (something undesirable):
>   *areas liable to flooding*

The word *flooding* is used here as a noun rather than the usual infinitive. The OED also supplies a [similarly helpful entry](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flood) for this form:

> (as noun flooding)
>   a serious risk of *flooding*

In other words, it's perfectly fine!

I suspect that *flooding* is preferred to just *flood* to avoid the ambiguity over *what* is flooding, as the word is not used only in reference to water. *"Road liable to flood"* could mean that the road itself could increase "in overwhelming quantities".

Comment: Perfectly fine, but _unusual_. Guess that's why it felt wrong to me. That's fair enough then I suppose.

Comment: "Liable," to me, has a legal connotation.Thus as shown by coleopterist above this leads to confusion. I believe that "Beware of possible flooding" is a better choice.

Comment: @Urbycoz: I have updated my answer to address your question.

Comment: @skullpatrol: Yes, [liable](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=liable) has one definition that is closely associated with the legal profession, but it is also a synonym for _apt_ or _prone_.  I don't think it's right to disqualify a word just because it has a secondary meaning, particularly when confusion is unlikely in context.  (Notice how I used _right_ and _just_ in that last sentence, which also have definitions pertaining to the legal system). No one is going to sue the road if it floods – although they might sue the highway department if no warning is provided :^)

Comment: The UK Highways Agency uses this form of words quite a lot. At least the triangle sign is descriptive in [this version of a similar sign](http://i.stack.imgur.com/euIyR.jpg).